# Spring Security & Multipart requests

Tags: spring, file-upload, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a @Controller protected with Spring Security and OAuth2 in which I am trying to let my users upload a file:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/image")
public class ImageController {

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_USER')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public @ResponseBody Account putImage(@RequestParam("title") String title, MultipartHttpServletRequest request, Principal principal){
        // Some type of file processing...
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Test upload: " + title);
        System.out.println("Test upload: " + request.getFile("file").getOriginalFilename());
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");

        return ((Account) ((OAuth2Authentication) principal).getPrincipal());
    }
}
```

When I try to upload a file and title, I get the following exception. I am setting the Content-Type header to multipart/form-data.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current request is not of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest]: SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@1aee75b7]]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(ServletRequestMethodArgumentResolver.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
```

How can I do file uploads behind Spring Security? It seems like the request never gets turned into a MultiPartHttpServerRequest and so it doesn't work?

If I change my method signature to take a @RequestParam MultipartFile, then I get an exception like:

```
DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'imageController'
DEBUG ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.tinsel.server.model.Account com.tinsel.server.controller.ImageController.putImage(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,java.security.Principal)]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?
DEBUG ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.tinsel.server.model.Account com.tinsel.server.controller.ImageController.putImage(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,java.security.Principal)]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?
DEBUG DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public com.tinsel.server.model.Account com.tinsel.server.controller.ImageController.putImage(java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,java.security.Principal)]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?
DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
```

...but I do have a MultipartResolver configured in my XML:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="268435456"/> <!-- 256 megs -->
</bean>
```

I did see [this blog post about getting this working under Spring 3.0](http://www.adamweigold.com/2012/01/using-multpartrequestresolvers-with.html) - but I'm trying to stay more up to date and am using 3.1 currently. Is there perhaps an updated fix?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that I'm using a PUT instead of a POST. Commons FileUpload is hard coded to only accept POST requests for files.

Check the [isMultipartContent method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.2.1/org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.java) there. To fix this, either use a POST or extend that class and override that method to work how you like.

I opened [FILEUPLOAD-214](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FILEUPLOAD-214) for this issue.

Comment: FILEUPLOAD-214 was resolved with WONTFIX. According to the authors `PUT` should not be used with `Multipart`

Comment: Yes, and eventually I did change to a POST rather than a PUT.

Comment: It's been fixed in version 1.3

Comment: After 3 years in 1.3.1 it's still there - [only POST](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3.1/org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.java?av=f).

Comment: This problem is still around. It's a tiny change, doesn't break _any_ HTTP specifications (it breaks REST, which, notably, is not HTTP, and therefore does not define multipart requests or `PUT`, and can safely be ignored here), and yet... people insist on not doing it. For... some reason. Great to see stupidity is alive and well everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

To solve the problem, do not use spring MultiPartHttpServerRequest, instead taking the request as HttpServletRequest, using the apache commons fileupload library to parse the request from PUT method, and processing the file. Here are some sample code:

```
ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());
List<FileItem> fileItems = fileUpload.parseRequest(httpServletRequest);
InputStream in = fileItems.get(0).getInputStream();
...
```

Comment: How to get a file in an HTTPRequest please help :P

Answer (score 2):

In Config.groovy

Make sure multipart is enabled,

```
// whether to disable processing of multi part requests
   grails.web.disable.multipart=false
```

In controller add Post method

```
def upload(){
    MultipartHttpServletRequest mpr = (MultipartHttpServletRequest)request;
    if(request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest)
            {
                CommonsMultipartFile f = (CommonsMultipartFile) mpr.getFile("myFile");
                println f.contentType
                f.transferTo()
                if(!f.empty)
                    flash.message = 'success'
                else
                    flash.message = 'file cannot be empty'
            }
    else
    flash.message = 'request is not of type MultipartHttpServletRequest'}
```

with these, I was able upload the file, nothing related Spring Security.

Answer (score -1):

you might take a look at https://github.com/joshlong/the-spring-tutorial which has an example demonstrating how to post to Spring MVC with Spring Security OAuth enabled. I even use HTML5 drag and drop to drag the image onto the screen then submit it via ajax to the server.