# Putting multipart request does not work

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, curl

Why doesn't this work? I am trying this against my Spring 3.2 MVC application. It works with POST requests.

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8080/bananas/1 --form data='{"description":"Hei", "status":"REJECTED"};type=application/json'
```

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to obtain request part:
>   data. The part is missing or multipart processing is not configured.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity updateQuestion(@PathVariable final int id,
                                         @RequestPart(value = "data") final Banana banana,
                                         @RequestPart(value = "image", required = false) final MultipartFile imageFile) {
```

Comment: You might find your answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/15058548/732771

Comment: I see the answer of Fielding but I am not sure if I understand it. Should I just change to POST instead and it would be correct usage or what?

Answer (score -1):

In reality PUT requests are supposed to work on Request Body (or payload) and not on Request Parameters. In that sense, servlet API & spring's handling is correct.

A better easier way to pass no data element from your jquery and javascript call.Pass your parameter as part of url.Means Set parameter in the url field.otherwise u have to do your code using GET.

Answer (score -1):

```
var x=10;
$.ajax({
            url: "/ritesh/" + x + "/patil" + "?param1=param2Val&..",
            type: "PUT",
            data: "",
            success: function(response) {
                // ....
            }
     });
```